# GITLAB: Save script output in variable .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
script:
        - ./scripts/getfilepath.py --unstripped ${BUILD_NUM}
```

This part of gitlab-ci.yml file.
I want to save output of `getfilepath.py` in a variable and use it later.

I tried doing this:

```
script:
        - VER_PATH=`./scripts/getfilepath.py --unstripped ${BUILD_NUM}`
```

But this saves the output of any `print` statements inside the file.

Is there a way to just get the result of the return value from the script?

Here is the content of getfilepath.py

```
def get_pdf():
    html_file = os.path.join(dirname, 'html_doc.html')
    pdf_file = os.path.join(dirname, 'pdf_doc.pdf')
    fill_html(sys.argv[1])
    convert_to_pdf(html_file, pdf_file)
    cleanup()
    return pdf_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use shell [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) with `shell = bash` in your runner.

Then, this should work :

```
script:
  - VER_PATH=$(./scripts/getfilepath.py --unstripped ${BUILD_NUM})
```

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. I tried this, but no luck.

Comment: could you put the content of `getfilepath.py` in your question ?